# Does SQL Server CASE expression not do short circuit?

Tags: sql-server, case, query-optimization

Appropriate if somebody could help us to optimize below query

As per execution plane it seems the else part sub query is always executing, irrespective of conditions.

Won't `CASE` be short circuited? Why is it executing, even though it is not necessary?

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('#Calculation') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Calculation;

SELECT 
    Result.IdDeckungsbeitrag,
    Result.wert AS Wert,
    REPLACE(@Formula, '<#PackagingCosts> ', Result.wert) AS Kalkulation
INTO
    #Calculation
FROM
    (SELECT 
         deck.IdDeckungsbeitrag,
         CASE
            WHEN lp.ID_VERPACKUNG_2 IS NULL
                    AND lp.ID_VERPACKUNG_3 IS NULL 
               THEN vg.VERPACKUNGSKOSTEN_PRO_EINHEIT * deck.Menge
               ELSE
           (
               SELECT SUM(temp.me) * vg.VERPACKUNGSKOSTEN_PRO_EINHEIT
               FROM
               (
                   SELECT SUM(gv.MENGE) AS me
                   FROM dbo.KUNDENRECHNUNG_POSITION krp
                       LEFT JOIN dbo.LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION lp
                           ON lp.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION = krp.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION
                       LEFT JOIN dbo.GEBINDE_VERLADEN gv
                           ON gv.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION = lp.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION
                       LEFT JOIN dbo.MATERIAL_BESTAND mb
                           ON mb.ID_MATERIAL_BESTAND = gv.ID_MATERIAL_BESTAND
                       LEFT JOIN dbo.MATERIAL_GEBINDE mg
                           ON mg.ID_MATERIAL_BESTAND = mg.ID_MATERIAL_BESTAND
                   WHERE mg.CHARGE_NUMMER = deck.Charge
                   GROUP BY mg.ID_VERPACKUNG
               ) temp
           )
           END AS wert
    FROM @DeckungsbeitragCalculationPositions_TVP deck
        LEFT JOIN dbo.KUNDENRECHNUNG_POSITION krp
            ON krp.ID_KUNDENRECHNUNG_POSITION = deck.IdDeckungsbeitrag
        LEFT JOIN dbo.LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION lp
            ON lp.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION = krp.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION
        LEFT JOIN dbo.VERPACKUNG vg
            ON vg.ID_VERPACKUNG = lp.ID_VERPACKUNG_1
    WHERE deck.IdMandant = @Id_Mandant
) Result;
```

Comment: `CASE` should short circuit, i.e. it stops at the first matching condition.  But, I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: What is `@DeckungsbeitragCalculationPositions_TVP`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of it as short-circuit or not. That's a procedural code mindset rather than a set-based mindset.

In SQL, the actual "execution" happens in the realm of table or index scans and seeks, hash matches, sorts, and the like. Pull data from different tables into a working set that will eventually produce the desired relational result.

Not seeing any real or projected execution plan, in this case (no pun intended), I suspect the query optimizer decided it was most efficient to first produce this result set in memory:

```
SELECT mg.ID_VERPACKUNG, mg.CHARGE_NUMMER, SUM(gv.MENGE) AS me
FROM dbo.KUNDENRECHNUNG_POSITION krp
LEFT JOIN dbo.LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION lp
    ON lp.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION = krp.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION
LEFT JOIN dbo.GEBINDE_VERLADEN gv
    ON gv.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION = lp.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION
LEFT JOIN dbo.MATERIAL_BESTAND mb
    ON mb.ID_MATERIAL_BESTAND = gv.ID_MATERIAL_BESTAND
LEFT JOIN dbo.MATERIAL_GEBINDE mg
    ON mg.ID_MATERIAL_BESTAND = mg.ID_MATERIAL_BESTAND
GROUP BY mg.ID_VERPACKUNG, mg.CHARGE_NUMMER
```

This is the subquery from the `ELSE` clause, minus the `WHERE` clause conditions and with additional info added to the `SELECT` to make the match more effective. If the query optimizer can't be confident of meeting the `WHEN` clause a high percentage of the time, it might believe producing this larger `ELSE` set once to match against as needed is more efficient. Put another way, if it thinks it will have to run that subquery a lot anyway, it may try to pre-load it for all possible data.

We don't know enough about your database to suggest real solutions, but indexing around the `ID_VERPACKUNG_2`, `ID_VERPACKUNG_3`, and `CHARGE_NUMMER` fields might help. You might also be able to use a CTE, temp table, or table variable to help Sql Server to a better job of caching this data just once.

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions of `where` are not met then the `else` will become active. If this is always the case then you would expect the following to return no rows:

```
select *
FROM @DeckungsbeitragCalculationPositions_TVP deck
LEFT JOIN dbo.KUNDENRECHNUNG_POSITION krp ON krp.ID_KUNDENRECHNUNG_POSITION = deck.IdDeckungsbeitrag
LEFT JOIN dbo.LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION lp ON lp.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION = krp.ID_LIEFERSCHEIN_POSITION
WHERE lp.ID_VERPACKUNG_2 IS NULL 
AND lp.ID_VERPACKUNG_3 IS NULL
```